# date value comparision in pyspark programming

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two columns in date type. let's say:

```
import datetime as dt
pass_date = "29-01-2020"
ref_date = dt.datetime.strptime(pass_date, "%d-%m-%Y").date()

curr_date = dt.datetime.now().date()

if ref_date == curr_date:
   print("Do the steps as per the logic")
else:
   print("Do the other way of code")
```

But, when I'm running the code part, I'm getting error and program is failed at if condition check with below message.

```
"Exception - Column object not callable"
```

Could you please check and update where I have done wrong in coding to compare two date values in if condition.

Comment: the code seems correct. Can you share more details about the problem ?

Comment: Where in your code is the error happening? I don't see any place where you're using a spark DataFrame. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure, I will update the additional details and code part.

Answer (score 0):

while checking condition convert both value into string using `str()`

```
import datetime as dt
pass_date = "29-01-2020"
ref_date = dt.datetime.strptime(pass_date, "%d-%m-%Y").date()

curr_date = dt.datetime.now().date()

if (str(ref_date) == str(curr_date)):
   print("Do the steps as per the logic")
else:
   print("Do the other way of code")
```